# Factory in AngularJS/Ionic return different value

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing an app in Ionic and I am brand new on all this angular js, cordova and ionic.

The thing is that I am trying to create a **service** that ask to an API for a response. I make it work perfectly in the **controller**:

```
$scope.search = function(icao) {
    console.log(icao);
    $scope.forecastfuture = [];

    $http.get("http://api.wunderground.com/............../UK/"+icao+".json")
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config){

          console.log(data);
          console.log(typeof data);
          for(i=0; i<36; i++){
            var day = data.hourly_forecast[i].FCTTIME.pretty;
            var maxtemp = data.hourly_forecast[i].temp.metric;
            var mintemp = data.hourly_forecast[i].dewpoint.metric;
            var feelslike = data.hourly_forecast[i].feelslike.metric;
            var humidity = data.hourly_forecast[i].humidity;
            var windspd = data.hourly_forecast[i].wspd.metric;
            var winddir = data.hourly_forecast[i].wdir.dir;
            var sky = data.hourly_forecast[i].condition;
            var precip = data.hourly_forecast[i].qpf.metric;
            var snow = data.hourly_forecast[i].snow.metric;
            var icon = data.hourly_forecast[i].icon_url;
            console.log(day);
            console.log(maxtemp);
            $scope.forecastfuture.push({
              id: i,
              day: day,
              maxtemp: maxtemp,
              mintemp: mintemp,
              feelslike: feelslike,
              humidity: humidity,
              windspd: windspd,
              winddir: winddir,
              sky: sky,
              precip: precip,
              snow: snow,
              icon: icon});
          }


    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
      console.log(data);
    });

  }
```

But now I am learning to create a **Factory**, because I will need this to be used **more than once**, but the return in the factory is different than in the **controller** you can see a **log** image here: [image: Log]

The first one is the **factory return**, as you can see the data is different than the second part, that is the response in the **controller** directly, the http.get.

My problem is that when I try to read anything from the factory it throw an error all the time. Here you have the code for the **factory**:

```
.factory('ForecastService', function(CurrentPosition, $http){
      var wresp;
      return{
          getForecastResponse: function(country, city){
                return   $http.get("http://api.wunderground.com/api/.........../q/"+country+"/"+city+".json")
                    .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                        console.log(data);
                    wresp = data;
                    return wresp;
                });
          },
          getDay: function(i){
            var day = wresp.hourly_forecast[i].FCTTIME.pretty;
            return day;
          },
          getMaxTemp: function(i){
            var maxtemp = wresp.hourly_forecast[i].temp.metric;
            return maxtemp;
          },
          getMinTemp: function(i){
            var mintemp = wresp.hourly_forecast[i].dewpoint.metric;
            return mintempo;
          },
          getFeelsLike: function(i){
            var feels = wresp.hourly_forecast[i].feelslike.metric;
            return feels;
          },
          getHumidity: function(i){
            var humidity = wresp.hourly_forecast[i].humidity;
            return humidity;
          },
          getWindSpd: function(i){
            var windspd = wresp.hourly_forecast[i].wspd.metric;
            return windspd;
          },
          getWinDir: function(i){
            var windir = wresp.hourly_forecast[i].wdir.dir;
            return windir;
          },
          getSky: function(i){
            var sky = wresp.hourly_forecast[i].condition;
            return sky;
          },
          getPrecip: function(i){
            var precip = wresp.hourly_forecast[i].qpf.metric;
            return precip;
          },
          getSnow: function(i){
            var snow = wresp.hourly_forecast[i].snow.metric;
            return snow;
          },
          getIcon: function(i){
            var icon = wresp.hourly_forecast[i].icon_url;
            return icon;
          }
      }

    })
```

and here the code in the **controller** to call this factory:

```
var forec = ForecastService.getForecastResponse("UK", "London");
var day = forec.getDay(1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct to `return` the `$http` call's result:

```
getForecastResponse: function(country, city){
  return $http.get(...)
}
```

This returns a promise to which you'd need to do `.then` (or `.success` for `$http`-specific promise, but I don't recommend it), because the response is not yet received by the time you attempted to do `.getDay`.

So, in the controller:

```
ForecastService
  .getForecastResponse("UK", "London")
  .then(function(){
     var day = ForecastService.getDay(1);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, I was starting to think that I was wrong in everything! This works :)

Comment: Careful, still... your use of `.success`, although works in your example, might indicate some misunderstanding. `.success` is different in a slight but meaningful way from `.than` - for example, `return wresp;` (within your `.success`) is completely useless, since this return is not caught by anything.

Comment: Thank you! If some one is wondering how to read the return of a promise in the next promise you can read it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16312760/1099945